# Laptop works on ethernet but not Desktop?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ethernet

I am relocating a workstation at a business and when I plug my work laptop into the Ethernet at the new desk location, works fine. When I plug the workstation into the new location, nothing appears and doesnt even seem to register a cable or activity. When I put the workstation back at the old location, works fine and is same gateway. My laptop can ping the old location and the workstation at the old location can ping me as well. Any ideas? Drivers are updated.

Comment: Does your laptop have Gigabit Ethernet, and if so, does it show 1Gbps link speed?

Comment: The card on laptop is a Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-AC 8260. Network is only 80Mbps

Comment: I219LM ethernet

Comment: What OS is on the problem PC?

Comment: Problem PC Win7. Laptop Win10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A number of things can be problematic here, either individually or in combination:

- The wall-outlet doesn't have all wires properly connected.
- The workstation has its NIC set to a fixed speed and the switch behind the outlet is configured for auto-negotiate.
- The other way around: Switch is fixed speed and workstation expects auto-negotiate.
- Either of the previous 2 may not affect the laptop as there can be big differences in how the NIC (or its driver) deals with that problem.
- The patch-cable between outlet and device may be flaky. (Again: may not effect each computer in the same way so the laptop may not notice.)
- The patch-cable on the switch-site may be flaky.
- If there is a patch-panel (on the side of the switch) the connection between switch-side patch-cable and patch-panel might be flaky.

Simply re-seating the connectors on all patch-cables involved (and/or replacing those patch-cables) may go a long way here.
And check the line-speed/auto-negotiate settings on the workstation and the switch.
Those are the most likely causes for this kind of behavior.

That it works fine for 1 device (the laptop) doesn't mean it is a 100% OK for any other device (the workstation).

Comment: So which part of this answer solved your issue @Mike Mccue

Comment: A flaky connection isn't going to consistently allow one device to connect but not another. If you have access to an Ethernet cable continuity tester, this would be the perfect time to use it; I would test the new outlet and the old outlet and look for wiring discrepancies.

Comment: @wrecclesham If 1 wire in pair 1-2 or 7-8 is flaky it may fail to negotiate on 1Gb/s nics without fallback to 100Mb/s. Additionally some rj45 plugs are shorter than others causing connection problems on especially the outer wires on some sockets because they dont’ push hard enough on the contacts, leading to the same issue.

Comment: @Tonny I think the second possibility is by far the most likely. I would start by trying a different network cable to connect the new outlet to the workstation, to quickly rule that out (i.e. the existing cable not making proper contact with the workstation's NIC.) If the OP doesn't have a spare network cable, swapping the ends of the same cable around might be all that's needed to get a better connection with the workstation's NIC (i.e. take the end from the wall outlet and connect it to the workstation and vice versa.)

Answer (score 0):

"Doesn't register a cable or activity" but it works back at the old location with the same gateway sounds like not all of the wires are firmly connecting.  The next things I would try :

Try different Ethernet cables at the new location.  Try a cheap USB Ethernet adapter, in case the workstation port is balky for some reason

It's possible that autonegotiate is broken or turned off on either the workstation or the new location, but that's a more complicated thing to look into.

Comment: Not sure if its cable related because when I plug my laptop into that same cable at the new location it works flawlessly. Makes it even more odd haha

Comment: @MikeMccue can you try a different Ethernet cable with the desktop at the new location?